# Entity Framework Unable to determine principal end of relationship. Multiple added entities may have same primary key

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm having some issues with EF.
Migrations go fine, but when I try to run update-database I get the error :

```
Unable to determine the principal end of the 'LeagueInsight.Models.Image_Passive' relationship. Multiple added entities may have the same primary key.
```

Here are my models and config:

Passive.cs

```
public class Passive
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SanitizedDescription { get; set; }

    // Navigation
    public virtual Image Image { get; set; }
    public virtual Champion Champion { get; set; }
}
```

Image.cs

```
public class Image
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Full { get; set; }
    public string Group { get; set; }
    public int H { get; set; }
    public string Sprite { get; set; }
    public int W { get; set; }
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }

    // Navigation
    public virtual Champion Champion { get; set; }
    public virtual ChampionSpell ChampionSpell { get; set; }
    public virtual Passive Passive { get; set; }
}
```

DBContext Configuration Partial:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Passive>()
    .HasRequired(p => p.Champion)
    .WithRequiredPrincipal(c => c.Passive);
modelBuilder.Entity<Info>()
    .HasRequired(i => i.Champion)
    .WithRequiredPrincipal(c => c.Info);
modelBuilder.Entity<Image>()
    .HasOptional(i => i.Champion)
    .WithRequired(c => c.Image);
modelBuilder.Entity<Image>()
    .HasOptional(i => i.Passive)
    .WithRequired(p => p.Image);

base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
```

It is just supposed to be a 1-1 relationship between the two, an I can't figure out why there would be multiple entities with the same Id here.

Edit: I was asked for the champion class:

```
public class Champion
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Blurb { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Lore { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Partype { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    // Navigation
    [InverseProperty("Ally")]
    public virtual ICollection<Tip> Allytips { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Enemy")]
    public virtual ICollection<Tip> Enemytips { get; set; }
    public virtual Image Image { get; set; }
    public virtual Info Info { get; set; }
    public virtual Passive Passive { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Recommended> Recommended { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Skin> Skins { get; set; }
    public virtual Stats Stats { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ChampionSpell> Spells { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that all of Passive and Info entities have Champion? Or it can be caused by an invalid foreign key (for example you want to use auto-generated id, but this id provided by the db and this is because you can't save)

Comment: I believe I fixed it by changing the order of addition in the configuration. Thanks for sparking the idea.

Comment: Show the `Champion` class

Comment: `ChampionSpell` might also be relevant, since there is a 1:1 (or 1:0-1) between `Champion` and `Image`, but a 1:n for `Champion`:`ChampionSpell` and a 1:1 (or 0-1) for `Image`:`ChampionSpell`

Comment: That for the help guys. I was able to get it working by redoing the 1-1 mappings.